# Getting error while running Service

Tags: wcf

I have created WCF service but while running the service I am getting below error:
Error:

> Failed to add a service. Service
>   metadata may not be accessible. Make
>   sure your service is running and
>   exposing metadata.
>   Error Details:
>   Warning: No code was generated.If you
>   were trying to generate a client, this
>   could be because the metadata
>   documents did not contain any valid
>   contracts or servicesor because all
>   contracts/services were discovered to
>   exist in /reference assemblies. Verify
>   that you passed all the metadata
>   documents to the tool.Warning: If you
>   would like to generate data contracts
>   from schemas make sure to use the
>   /dataContractOnly option.

Code:

```
namespace WCFTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public List<Employee> GetDetails()
        {
            List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>()
            {
               new Employee(){Fname="AA",Lname="BB",EmpId=1,Desg="A"},
               new Employee(){Fname="CC",Lname="DD",EmpId=1,Desg="B"},
               new Employee(){Fname="EE",Lname="FF",EmpId=1,Desg="C"},
               new Employee(){Fname="GG",Lname="HH",EmpId=1,Desg="D"},
               new Employee(){Fname="II",Lname="JJ",EmpId=1,Desg="A"},
               new Employee(){Fname="KK",Lname="LL",EmpId=1,Desg="B"}
            };
            return emp;
        }
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Employee))]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Lname { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Employee : Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Desg { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WCFTest
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1
    {
        public List<Employee> GetData(int value)
        {
            EmployeeDetails ed = new EmployeeDetails();
            return ed.GetDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

However I could see metadata is exposed in web.config.

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any clue where I am going wrong?

EDIT: I think the reason behind the error is I am using a class as a service contract, now when I change it to an Interface, things work as expected, not sure why I am getting the error if I am specifying the class as service contract.

Comment: I don't see any <services> node in your web.config..... also: how are you trying to create the proxy from the service: Add Service Reference in Visual Studio or running svcutil on the command line ??

Comment: no I am not trying to create any proxy, what I did was- create new->project>WCF application and then added this code, and tried to run the WCF sln.

Comment: The default WCF application works this way(I mean the default one without anu code change in C# or web.config)

Comment: I am not hosting.I just create a wcf application and then running the sln.now when u run the sln, u get  dialogue box "WCF TEST Client" ,now while doing this I am getting the error

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `<services>` node in your config - you're not configuring a service at all - so there's nothing there to connect to.

You need to extend your config to include something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="WCFTest.EmployeeDetails">
         <endpoint name="Default" 
                   address="/default"
                   binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                   contract="WCFTest.EmployeeDetails" />
         <endpoint kind="mexEndpoint" address="/mex" />
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now, you have a service with a service and a metadata endpoint, and now your WCF Test Client should be able to find something to connect to....