# WCF Service Application template throws error when debugging

Tags: wcf

I trying to use VS2010 WCF Service Application template to create a new WCF service. After editing the default service contract and updating the implementation of this this contract I tried to run the service from within VS (F5).

The WCF Test Client starts and throws and error while trying to add my service.

> Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

I have not made and changes to the web.config. I am having the same problem posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846595/getting-error-while-runing-service)

However, unlike the other posting, my service contract is an interface. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

CheckIn.svc

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace org.myorg.pkggateway
{

    public class PackageCheckIn : IPackageCheckIn
    {
        public bool CheckIn(int value)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true);
                sw.WriteLine(value.ToString());
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

IPackageCheckIn.cs:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace org.myorg.pkggateway {

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPackageCheckIn
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool CheckIn(int value);
    }


   }
```

Web.config (unchanged from autogen):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**update**

It seems that when I renamed the default .svc file that the template creates refactor did not rename this file everywhere. There must be a reference to it somewhere else. However when I search my entire solution for use of "Service1.svc" it does not exist anywhere. Does anyone know how to clean this up? I even did a search on the file system for a file containing this filename and came up with nothing. I cannot find where VS is still referencing this .svc file. Anyone have this problem?

I have deleted the service altogether and created a new one and the problem still persists.

**update**

When I run my solution the WCF test client fails to load the deleted service. However the one that does exist works fine. I guess I just have to ignore the fact that I cannot get the test client to "forget" about this service.

Comment: What happens if you browse to the .svc file in your application?

Comment: I don't see any endpoints declared in your web config. At what address do you expose the service? Do you use the development server or IIS?

Comment: @Pencho - if @Nick is using WCF 4.0, he doesn't need to declare endpoints; the default ones will be used.

Comment: Since no endpoints are defined, the "default endpoints" are created - at the base address of the service (i.e., the address to the .svc file). The first thing to try should be to browse to the .svc file itself - if there is a compilation error or some deployment error, it should be shown at that point.

Comment: @carlosfigueira This is a .net 4.0 application. Since I cannot run this application in VS I don't understand how I might browser to the svc file

Comment: @carlosfigueira I hit the url from the browser and you are right. I see the error that my svc file cannot be found. It would appear that 'refactor' has let me down and did not update the file name everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Given that you had a problem with the .svc file, one possible solution is to recreate that file. On VS, create a new *text* file, rename it to YourServiceName.svc, and add the following content:

```
<% @ServiceHost Service="org.myorg.pkggateway.PackageCheckIn" Language="C#" debug="true" %>
```

Then try browsing to the .svc file (or using the WCF Test Client to open the URL of the .svc file).

Comment: Yes.. the svc file exists. The problem is the server continues to look for a service called, Service1.svc. I cannot find any reference to this service anywhere in my solution.

Comment: Where is the server looking for Service1.svc? When you try to build your app, browse to it, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the properties of the Project and navigate to the Web tab.  Then update the Specific Page to the renamed service.